# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file URLClassPath.class

Tags: java, eclipse

May I know how to handle the source not found error while debugging the java code in Eclipse IDE
I got the error -
**The source attachment does not contain the source for
the file URLClassPath.class.**

Comment: Is your application being compiled against and run with a JDK rather than just a JRE?